# Java Regex for custom function

Tags: java, regex, match

I'm looking for a Regex pattern that matches the following, but I'm kind of stumped so far. I'm not sure how to grab the results of the two groups I want, marked by `id`, and `attr`.

Should match:

- `account[id].attr`
- `account[anotherid].anotherattr`

These should respectively return `id, attr`,
and `anotherid, anotherattr`

Any tips?

Comment: Can we see your attempts to solve this task? How do you think regex which can match `account[xxx].yyy` may look like?

Comment: it's seems unclear. Please explain a bit more.

Comment: I guess I just want to match account[sometext].moretext and grab the sometext and moretext fields. It seems possible!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a complete solution mapping your `id` -> `attribute`s:

```
String[] input = {
        "account[id].attr",
        "account[anotherid].anotherattr"
};
//                           | literal for "account"
//                           |      | escaped "["
//                           |      |  | group 1: any character 
//                           |      |  |   | escaped "]"
//                           |      |  |   |  | escaped "."
//                           |      |  |   |  |  | group 2: any character
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("account\\[(.+)\\]\\.(.+)");
Map<String, String> output = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
// iterating over input Strings
for (String s: input) {
    // matching
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    // finding only once per input String. Change to a while-loop if multiple instances
    // within single input
    if (m.find()) {
        // back-referencing group 1 and 2 as key -> value
        output.put(m.group(1), m.group(2));
    }
}
System.out.println(output);
```

**Output**

```
{id=attr, anotherid=anotherattr}
```

**Note**

In this implementation, "incomplete" inputs such as `"account[anotherid]."` will not be put in the `Map` as they don't match the `Pattern` at all.

In order to have these cases put as `id` -> `null`, you only need to add a `?` at the end of the `Pattern`.

That will make the last group optional.

Comment: hmm http://snag.gy/ZHHzk.jpg shows that it doesn't match... otherwise looks good!!

Comment: @phouse512 Quoth the server, `404`. Although testing your Java `Pattern`s with Java has the clear advantage over web tools of actually seeing it matched with the Java regex engine.

Comment: @phouse512 same answer (minus the `404`): probably a different engine, or different way to handle escapes (i.e. single vs double).